# Mkdir throws a warning, when it should be a bool?

Tags: php, mkdir

so the popular mkdir() function in php throws me a warning in the following code:

```
public function check_dir($dir, $create_dir = false) {
    if (is_dir ( $dir )) {
        return true;
    } elseif ($create_dir == true) {
        return mkdir ( $dir );
    }

    return false;
}
```

Its simple to know whats going on. So I won't explain. But on the mkdir() line I get:

> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/AisisCore/FileHandling/File.php on line 70

So while its a warning and nothing more, you should never turn of warnings in live, or any kind of error for that fact. So how do I deal with this when its clearly states it returns true or false and not a warning or fatal?

Comment: can you get write permissions to your server? that should fix it

Comment: Actually, you *should* turn off warnings in "live" (assuming by "live" you mean "production"). You should never turn off warnings during *development*.

Comment: also, you can turn off error/warning messages to the display and send them to a log file instead

Comment: @meagar wrong. Never turn off any error any where. They are meant to help you debug things. some times things can go wonky in live when its not going wonky in dev land. It is odd, it has happened.

Comment: You should *not* turn off warnings or errors in _ANY_ environment. Rather, you should change them in production from stdout to a logfile instead. And you should _ABSOLUTELY_ turn off `display_errors` in production.

Comment: @THeWebs if you want to expose the integrity of your application then do not turn of errors in a production environment.

Comment: @TheWebs No, you're pretty much wrong. If you feel like vomiting back-end PHP noise onto the page in your production environment, you're welcome to do so, but when you have the ability to *log* errors instead, your position is pretty indefensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can establish a custom error handler, which is a good practice in general: http://www.php.net/set-error-handler

You can use this to handle any PHP errors in any way you find appropriate. Short of that, you would have to either turn off error/warning logging (as you say, not a good practice), or use @ suppression (which should be avoided in general, but might be suitable in this case.)

Personally I would agree that a function that returns true/false to indicate failure already doesn't need to issue a warning if it fails. But, that's PHP for you.

Comment: so is it appropriate in this case to suppress the warning as I already deal with this returning false?

Comment: I would say yes, in this case, using `@` error suppression is probably fine. It's just something that's so easily overused/abused that I try to avoid it if at all possible. But in this case, where it seems like the API itself is working against you, it makes sense to me to suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn warning off in production servers ... But better still .. you can check for permission in your code ...

```
function checkDir($dir, $createDir = false) {
    if ($createDir === true) {
        if (is_dir($dir))
            return true;
        $baseDir = dirname($dir);
        if (! is_dir($baseDir) || ! is_writable($baseDir)) {
            return false;
        }
        return mkdir($dir);
    } else {
        return is_dir($dir);
    }
    return false;
}
```